# Live monitoring on web server logs by tailing the webserver access log

Tags: nginx, web-server, monitoring, performance-monitoring, top

I am looking for a way to find who causes high load on my nginx web server but I do have too many requests per minutes to figure it out which one is the real cause.

I want a solution that would work like `top` but that would give me starts like

```
ip |  requests | average response time | total response time
---|-----------|-----------------------|--------------------
```

Every line looks like:

```
 10.80.3.169 - - [02/Nov/2012:12:15:37 +0000] "POST /pages/docreatepage.action HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "http://example.com/pages/docreate" "Mozilla..." "-" 1.074 1.074
```

So all I need form each line is the first part (IP) and last part (duration) and to count them and display starts every few seconds.

Is there a tool that is able do to this, or should I have to code it myself?

Comment: I'm glad sticking with apache let me use apachetop and mod status.

Comment: [gltail](http://www.fudgie.org/) might to the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

Likely you're looking for [ngxtop](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ngxtop).

> Real-time metrics for nginx server
>
> ngxtop parses your nginx access log and outputs useful, top-like,
>   metrics of your nginx server. So you can tell what is happening with
>   your server in real-time.

Comment: Another similar tool is [wtop](https://github.com/ClockworkNet/wtop)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like ntop?

http://www.ntop.org/